# How to see cpu and gpu usage per animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

**Situation:**
I have a website with multiple jQuery, Javascript and CSS animations. These animations make my site slow and stutter at times.

**Question:**
How can I see the cpu and gpu usage per specific animation within my website? I know how to see the entire usage of the website but not of an singular animation.

**What have I tried?**

- Google Dev Tools
- Firefox Dev Tools
- Console.profile / Console.profileend

Comment: There are no browser-based tools to monitor the CPU usage of JS/CSS. Mostly because good, well optimised code should never come close to reaching a CPU bottleneck. All you can really do is use is the performance tab of Task Manager

Comment: There is a Task Manager dedicated in Chrome for CPU usage and JS Memory

Answer (score 0):

There are several tools in Chrome Dev which could help you out.
When analysis animation you should look at the information for a specific frame, or range of frame.

I would suggest starting from this document:

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/timeline

Consider evaluating:

- Frames mode, which shows your page's rendering performance.
- Analyzing Timeline recordings

In Firefox you can use the **frame-rate** value as an indicator of bottlenecks, specially for animation related issues, you can read more about these tools here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Performance/Frame_rate

You can also see how much `GPU` time was spent compositing each frame diving in the build-in profile in Firefox:, more information can be found here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Performance/Profiling_with_the_Built-in_Profiler

Comment: You can see the level of CPU and memory usage for you entire application selecting "Task Manager" from `Chrome/More Tools` or `Shift + Esc` (but probably you know already that).